# How to pass a control to a function when I use jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The "#SelectView" is a Select control, the code A works well, I hope to write a function to do it,

but both Method 1 and Method 2 are failed, why? How can I write the fucntion?

**Code A**

```
$("#SelectView").change(function () {
    temp.view = $("#SelectView").get(0).selectedIndex;
    window.location.href = CreateJumpLink(temp);
});
```

**Method 1**

```
SetJumpForSelectChanged('#SelectView', temp.view);

function SetJumpForSelectChanged(name, par) {
    $(name).change(function () {
        par = $(name).get(0).selectedIndex;
        window.location.href = CreateJumpLink(temp); 
    });
}
```

**Method 2**

```
SetJumpForSelectChanged( $('#SelectView'), temp.view);

function SetJumpForSelectChanged(name, par) {
    name.change(function () {
        par = $(name).get(0).selectedIndex;
        window.location.href = CreateJumpLink(temp); 
    });
}
```

**Added**

```
function ClassURLPar() {
    this.filename;
    this.diskindex=0;
    this.diskcount=1;
    this.imagefilter = 0;
    this.sortby = 0;
    this.path = "/";
    this.view = 0;
}


var temp = jQuery.extend(true, {}, mURL);
```

Comment: what temp are you reffering to

Comment: You should not reassign `var`s that are in your arguments, for one. You don't do anything with `par`. What is `CreateJumpLink(temp)`, anyways?

Comment: Would you please see my added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, when passing a primitive (like a string), you don't pass by reference. Thus in the first one, you pass in `temp.view`, which exists as `par` inside the function. You modify `par`, but then do nothing with it, instead you pass the original `temp` to `CreateJumpLink`.

Confusingly (if you're new to JS) when your argument is an object, then it *is* passed by reference.

```
SetJumpForSelectChanged('#SelectView', temp);

function SetJumpForSelectChanged(name, tempReference) {
    $(name).change(function () {
        tempReference.view = $(name).get(0).selectedIndex;
        window.location.href = CreateJumpLink(tempReference); // or temp, same result if it's in scope
    });
}
```

If `temp` is in scope in both places, then you don't need to pass it in at all.